# Is the 1920 CTR Printer-Lister a Ticketograph?

Tags: history

In [an answer about screen formats](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5634/611) Raffzahn  wrote:

> "In 1920 the Tabulating Machine Company (originally The Hollerith Electric Tabulating System, now part of CTR Holding) introduced a new printer-lister system with 132 columns. While not the first to do so (*8), it became the de facto standard, thus setting the 132 characters for tabulating output - what later evolved into mainframe printers (and everything else meant to produce a ledger output)."

I am trying to find evidence that this "new printer-lister system with 132 columns" to which  Raffzahn is referring is the Ticketograph machine acquired by C-T-R in 1921.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find evidence that this "new printer-lister system with 132 columns" to which Raffzahn is referring is the Ticketograph machine acquired by C-T-R in 1921.

Well, you won't, as it simply isn't. the Ticketograph is a very special recording/printing device. Essentially a process or program in hardware. A Printer-Lister is a device that can either take records from a tabulator and print them, or read punch cards and print their content. It operates, quite like many printers later, on endless paper, not on production cards (*1).

Also, the first IBM (well, CTR) Printer-Lister (at that time there was no model number, it was just called that) was introduced in 1920, while CTR acquired *Pierce Accounting Machine Company* and thus the Ticketograph only a year later in 1921.

The Printer-Lister wasn't the first printer used for tabulating and/or listing, but it divided a ledger sized paper into 132 columns. Which the [original question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5634/611) was about. It was as well only numeric, as (AFAIK) the alphanumeric printer is a separate and later development.

It's development as tabulating printer was a gradual, and CTR a late comer. While they had a firm hold in the tabulating market, their equipment still did not print, but 'only' count (add) up on a set of displays (Five for the tabulator CTR sold in 1914), one for each sum. Results were manually recorded. The only preparation was the insertion of Stop-Cards, cards with a specific encoding punched that, when detected, simply halted the card feed. BTW, another patent of Hollerith. While stopped the operator would read all gauges record them, by hand, as subtotal, reseted all counters and restarted the machine. Totals were done by hand. Stop-Cards were interpersed into the stack in intervals the operator did feel fine about. It wasn't an exact science but educated guesswork.

The situation for CTR was much like with any company with a reasonable large market share, its policies stopped being about cutting edge technology and focused on keeping their business as it is. This let other companies come up with improvements from keypuches to printers. One of this companies them was the [Powers Accounting Machine Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Legrand_Powers) of New York. Their [Automatic Tabulating Machine Model B](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Powers_Automatic_Tabulating_Machine_Model_%22B%22.gif) incooperates eventually the first printer. Except, it didn't print on regular sheets but only a small stripe of endless paper like a cash register (*2).

During the 1910s Powers improved thereon on thus became a major competition for CTR. But not as dangerous as one would (today) assume, switching for a printing tabulator wasn't as obvious as it may seam today. Many customers stayed with operators noting the result. After all,that's a classic 90% solution, why invest more. Still, IBM had to react, and during the 1910s the new CEO Watson reacted and did set a team (*3) to create a printing tabulating machine.

The result was the 1920 Tabulator-Printer or Printer-Lister, depending on the configuration, using 132 columns (*4). 132 column is exactly what's needed to print a ledger page - this was another innovative idea of the team, as it enabled the tabulator to directly print the page for be filed (well, after adding the text part by hand or with a tabulator carriage typewriter.

---

Now, you asked for references, were it gets hard, as I'm not much inclined to dig thru my books to find them. Except, a first stop - and a must for everyone into early (IBM) Computers - is, well, *"IBM's Early Computers"*, MIT-Press, 1986, ISBN 0-262-02225-7. The first half of chapter 1 covers this development.

[image]

Another book worth peeking in might be *"Punched-Card Systems and the Early Information Explosion 1880–1945"* by Lars Heide, ISBN 978-0801891434. Its third chapter *'Challengers to Hollerith'* covers as well some of this.

Then again, with the right keywords I think it should be doable to find pictures of early printing tabulators. Many institutions are proud of their heritage. For example this page shows exactly the [printing-tabulator in question](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/tabulator.html) (Now called Model III) of the [Columbia University Computing History](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/index.html) shows pictures and descriptions.

[image]

Development of this first printing tabulator cumulated in 1933 with the [Type 285](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/285.html) (*5)

[image]

(One got to love this contemporary picture :))

Of course some background knowledge is helpful in selecting found sources. To me it's simply stuff I learned. I started my career right when punch cards where about to vanish from every way usage, so I still had to learn it. From the 'old guys' and books like this 1970s beauty:

[image]

---

P.S.: I still know how to do COBOL, although it has been rarely used lately. So I'm not only curious how you incorporate this information, but it might be as well interesting to see what image of COBOL is presented today. So please put it online and give us a hint when available.

---

*1 - And a device that would print text on top of a punch card is called an *Interpreter*.

*2 - Also, unlike implied in the Wiki entry, a unit could only print a single counter on its own paper stripe. Additional units could be added. up to a total of 7 printers, the tabulator unit and up to 6 counter/printer extensions (Again the Wiki description is somewhat misleading - and no, I'm not correcting it, I have given up on fighting fan boy hordes on Wiki).

*3 - During development the team did crank out several substantial improvements to CTR's tabulating machines. Two important innovations were added by the team already ahead of the printer:

- **Group Control** which replaced the Stop-Card.
- **Automated Counter Reset**

With Group Control a card was read twice. First time to be tabulated, and a second time in parallel with the next card. This time a selectable set of columns, called 'group indicator' was compared between the cards and the machine halted if they differed. Subtotals (still recorded by hand) did no longer need Stop-Cards, but as well were now no longer taken at random, often meaningless points, but whenever an accounting criteria changed.

Automatic Counter Reset on the other hand made sure that all counters were zeroed when the machine was restarted - before the operator had to reset each if the counters manually.

Both inventions were quite essential to IBM's success during the 1920s. And both may seam incredible basic from today's view, but then again, who of us has never forgotten to page at the right moment or clear some variable before reuse?

*4 - Not all 132 columns could always be used at a time, but any of the 132 could be configured to be used.

*5 - At that time IBM had reorganized their naming scheme into 'meaningful' numbers.